# How to call my constructor in my test class?

Tags: unit-test

I get this error

> Constructor not defined: [vf_CommunityPlanGoalPSetting_Cntrlr].()

This is how my constructor is setup in my controller.

```
public vf_CommunityPlanGoalPSetting_Cntrlr(ApexPages.StandardController controller) 
{
```

What do I need to put in the parenthesis on line 2 in my test class below:

> vf_CommunityPlanGoalPSetting_Cntrlr(**What goes here?**)

```
  static testMethod void unitTest () 
  {   
     Test.setCurrentPageReference(new PageReference('Page.vf_CommunityPlanGoalPSetting'));

     vf_CommunityPlanGoalPSetting_Cntrlr controller = new vf_CommunityPlanGoalPSetting_Cntrlr();  

     Test.StartTest();

     Test.StopTest();
```

Comment: Have you tried passing in the Id of whatever record uses the Standard Controller?

Comment: what would be the syntax for this?

Comment: I meant the record itself sorry. See my answer anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming this controller uses the Account object, it'd look something like this:

```
Account a = [SELECT Id FROM Account LIMIT 1];

vf_CommunityPlanGoalPSetting_Cntrlrcontroller = new vf_CommunityPlanGoalPSetting_Cntrlr(new ApexPages.StandardController(a));
```

You need to pass in a record.

You should create an Account record in your @testSetup method, or you can create it within the test method itself.